# Backbone stops listening for events after n times event is fired

Tags: backbone.js, websocket

I'm writing an in-browser remote for the mpd music daemon using the unofficial [mpdjs library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mpd) and backbone.js, with the [backbone.collectionView](http://rotundasoftware.github.io/backbone.collectionView/) library. Data is transmitted between the browser and the server through websockets.

The following block of code controls the event firing:

```
App.Views.PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend
  template: _.template(JST.player())
  events:
    'click .song': 'changeSong'

  changeSong: (e) ->
    classList = e.currentTarget.classList
    classList.remove('song')
    classList.remove('ui-sortable-handle')

    songId = classList[0]
    socket.send("play-song:#{songId.split('-')[1]}")

  render: () ->
    emp = @model.toJSON()
    html = @template(emp)
    html = $(html).addClass("song song-#{emp.id}")[0]
    @$el.append(html)

App.Views.PlaylistView = new Backbone.CollectionView
  el: $('.queue')
  selectable: true
  collection: App.CurrentPlaylist
  modelView: App.Views.PlayerView
```

These are the relevant models and collections:

```
App.Models.Song = Backbone.Model.extend
  defaults:
    track: ''
    title: ''
    artist: ''
    album: ''
    length: ''

App.Collections.Playlist = Backbone.Collection.extend
  model: App.Models.Song
App.CurrentPlaylist = new App.Collections.Playlist
```

When the app starts and connects to the WebSocketServer, the following code populates the following markup:

```
 // this is wrapped in socket.onmessage, and is only called once
  parseTime = (time) ->
    min = Math.floor(parseInt(time, 10) / 60)
    sec = Math.floor(parseInt(time, 10) % 60)
    if sec < 10
      sec = "0#{sec}"
    "#{min}:#{sec}"

  for key, value of data.playlist
    song = new App.Models.Song(
      id: value.Id
      track: value.Track.split('/')[0]
      title: value.Title
      artist: value.Artist
      album: value.Album
      length: parseTime(value.Time)
    )
    App.CurrentPlaylist.add(song)

  App.Views.PlaylistView.render()

// this is the markup it spits out
<table class="queue pure-table collection-list selectable" tabindex="0">
  <div data-model-cid="c3">
    <tr class="song song-1">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Reykjavik Blues</td>
      <td>Inf</td>
      <td>The Go Round</td>
      <td>2:06</td>
      </tr>
  </div>
  <div data-model-cid="c4">
    <tr class="song song-2">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Wasting Time</td>
      <td>Inf</td>
      <td>The Go Round</td>
      <td>2:30</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

When 'play-song-2' is sent to the server, the following function is called. The '2' is parsed out of the 'play-song-2' so this function works correctly.

```
function playSong(ws, songId) {
  mpdConnection.sendCommand('playid ' + songId, function(err, msg) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // this is a helper function that takes the plain text response
    // and organizes it into a javascript object
    msg = msgToObject(msg);  
    msg.type = 'song-update';
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
  });
}
```

The issue I'm facing, however, is that when the page is loaded, `changeSong(e)` is fired virtually instantly after `.song` is clicked. If, however, there are n amount of songs on the page, the page stops listening for events after n clicks.

**Update**: I appear to have accidentally fixed this issue with a few layout changes. I modified the view so that instead of inserting a div, on render a tr would be inserted:

```
App.Views.PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend
  tagName: 'tr'
  template: _.template(JST.player())
  events:
    'click': 'changeSong'
```

and I took away the .song class selector, opting to listen for an event on all clicks. With the selector, the original, broken behavior still stands, but without it, the player works very well. I'm still unsure of why this actually worked, however, so I'm offering a bounty for anyone who can explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your view

```
App.Views.PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend
  events:
    'click .song': 'changeSong'

  changeSong: (e) ->
    classList = e.currentTarget.classList
    classList.remove('song')
    # your logic
```

Now as per your `events` hash, it says whenever an element with the class name `song` is clicked, then execute the method `changeSong`. But inside `changeSong` you are removing the classname `song`. Therefore, the event handler is run only once ! because once it ran the class name `song` is removed.

So if you have like 4 songs, click four of them once & then after none of the click will fire the `changeSong` method. Does it make things clear ?